# I don't understand the notation of the Average Treatment effect on the Treated

Tags: probability, causality

The `Average Treatment effect on the Treated` is a formula in causal inference which calculates the effect of some treatment on the treated group.

$ATT = E[Y(A{=}1)-Y(A{=}0)| A{=}1]$

I don't understand how the notation of this expression relates to how it is calculated. For instance, given the sample data:

```
Y(A=1) | Y(A=0)
--------------------
10.0   | 
20.0   | 
30.0   |
       | 1
       | 2
       | 3
```

The $ATT = 54=(10+20+30)-(1+2+3)$, where the values under $Y(A=1)$ correspond to the effect for a few samples with treatment $A=1$, and the values under $Y(A=0)$ correspond to the effect for a few samples with treatment $A=0$.

The expression $|A=1$ in the original expression makes me think $({=}1)−({=}0)$ should only be calculated over values in which $A=1$. To me, the following expression makes more sense:

$ATT = E[Y(A{=}1) | A{=}1 - Y(A{=}0)| A{=}0]$

or maybe even

$ATT = E[Y(A{=}1) | A{=}1] - E[Y(A{=}0)| A{=}0]$

If you interpret $E$ as the calculation of the average effect across a distribution. What am I misunderstanding about the relevant notation?

Comment: [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308397/why-is-average-treatment-effect-different-from-average-treatment-effect-on-the-t) may be helpful.

Comment: I do (kind of, I think) have a conceptual understanding of the difference between ATE and ATT; ATE can be calculated when you have both the effect of the treatment and the counterfactual for each person, and is more of a theoretical concept. This is in contrast to ATT, which uses the formula specified above. Really, while I definitely need to understand the domain more thoroughly, my question really is related to the notation of this specific expression, and the usage of "|A=1"